File tab is not showing in the Link Browser of the RTE Editor TYPO3 Backend
I have a project that i migrated from v11 to version 12.
In the Rich Text Editor when you select some text and to link it to a file uploaded of the Link Browser (To add a link to a pdf file).
Now the Tab File in the RTE to upload a file link disappeared, is there some configuration to add the "File" Tab ?
Please take a look at the screenshot to see that the tab for "File" is not there anymore after the upgrade.

I have this configuration in my setup:

I have tried to delete the configuration of bootstrap and just use the full preset = full, but still not getting the File link in the link browser.
I also tried to deleted any loaded TsConfig from the Backend.
I also uninstalled the bootstrap_package plugin and the theme plugin that running from the extension manager, no success yet.
I add bootstrap_package tsconfig for the TsConfig code here:
imports:
- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }

editor:
externalPlugins:
bootstrappackage_address:
resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Address/plugin.min.js"
bootstrappackage_box:
resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Box/plugin.min.js"
bootstrappackage_columns:
resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Columns/plugin.min.js"
bootstrappackage_indent:
resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Indent/plugin.min.js"
bootstrappackage_table:
resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/CKEditor/Plugins/Table/plugin.min.js"
config:
    contentsCss: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/Css/bootstrap5-rte.min.css"

    stylesSet:
        - { name: "Lead", element: "p", attributes: { 'class': 'lead' } }
        - { name: "Small", element: "small" }

        - { name: "Table", element: "table", attributes: { 'class': 'table' } }
        - { name: "Table Striped", element: "table", attributes: { 'class': 'table table-striped' } }
        - { name: "Table Bordered", element: "table", attributes: { 'class': 'table table-bordered' } }
        - { name: "Table Condensed", element: "table", attributes: { 'class': 'table table-condensed' } }

        - { name: "Row Active", element: "tr", attributes: { 'class': 'table-active' } }
        - { name: "Row Success", element: "tr", attributes: { 'class': 'table-success' } }
        - { name: "Row Info", element: "tr", attributes: { 'class': 'table-info' } }
        - { name: "Row Warning", element: "tr", attributes: { 'class': 'table-warning' } }
        - { name: "Row Danger", element: "tr", attributes: { 'class': 'table-danger' } }

        - { name: "Cell Active", element: "td", attributes: { 'class': 'table-active' } }
        - { name: "Cell Success", element: "td", attributes: { 'class': 'table-success' } }
        - { name: "Cell Info", element: "td", attributes: { 'class': 'table-info' } }
        - { name: "Cell Warning", element: "td", attributes: { 'class': 'table-warning' } }
        - { name: "Cell Danger", element: "td", attributes: { 'class': 'table-danger' } }

        - { name: "Button Default", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-default' } }
        - { name: "Button Primary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-primary' } }
        - { name: "Button Secondary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-secondary' } }
        - { name: "Button Tertiary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-tertiary' } }
        - { name: "Button Quaternary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-quaternary' } }
        - { name: "Button Success", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-success' } }
        - { name: "Button Info", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-info' } }
        - { name: "Button Warning", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-warning' } }
        - { name: "Button Danger", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-danger' } }

        - { name: "Button Outline Default", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-default' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Primary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-primary' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Secondary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-secondary' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Tertiary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-tertiary' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Quaternary", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-quaternary' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Success", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-success' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Info", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-info' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Warning", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-warning' } }
        - { name: "Button Outline Danger", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'btn btn-outline-danger' } }

        - { name: "Link Arrow", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-arrow' } }
        - { name: "Link Chevron", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-chevron' } }
        - { name: "Link Page", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-page' } }
        - { name: "Link Folder", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-folder' } }
        - { name: "Link File", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-file' } }
        - { name: "Link External", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-external' } }
        - { name: "Link Mail", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-mail' } }
        - { name: "Link Globe", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'link-globe' } }

        - { name: "List Unstyled", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-unstyled' } }
        - { name: "List Inline", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-inline' } }
        - { name: "List Check", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-check' } }
        - { name: "List Info", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-info' } }
        - { name: "List Warning", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-warning' } }
        - { name: "List Ban", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-ban' } }
        - { name: "List Chevron", element: "ul", attributes: { 'class': 'list-chevron' } }

        - { name: "Lowercased text", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-lowercase' } }
        - { name: "Uppercased text", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-uppercase' } }
        - { name: "Capitalized text", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-capitalize' } }
        - { name: "Muted", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-muted' } }
        - { name: "Primary", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-primary' } }
        - { name: "Secondary", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-secondary' } }
        - { name: "Tertiary", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-tertiary' } }
        - { name: "Quaternary", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-quaternary' } }
        - { name: "Success", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-success' } }
        - { name: "Info", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-info' } }
        - { name: "Warning", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-warning' } }
        - { name: "Danger", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'text-danger' } }

    toolbarGroups:
        - { name: styles, groups: [ format, styles ] }
        - { name: basicstyles, groups: [ basicstyles ] }
        - { name: paragraph, groups: [ list, indent, blocks, align ] }
        - "/"
        - { name: links, groups: [ links ] }
        - { name: clipboard, groups: [ clipboard, cleanup, undo ] }
        - { name: editing, groups: [ spellchecker ] }
        - { name: insert, groups: [ insert ] }
        - { name: tools, groups: [ table, specialchar ] }
        - { name: document, groups: [ mode ] }

    format_tags: "p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;pre"

    justifyClasses:
        - text-left
        - text-center
        - text-right
        - text-justify

    extraPlugins:
        - justify
        - autolink
        - bootstrappackage_address
        - bootstrappackage_box
        - bootstrappackage_columns
        - bootstrappackage_indent
        - bootstrappackage_table

    removePlugins:
        - image

    removeButtons:
        - Anchor
        - Underline
        - Strike

classesAnchor:
    page:
        class: 'link-page'
        type: 'page'
    folder:
        class: 'link-folder'
        type: 'folder'
    file:
        class: 'link-file'
        type: 'file'
    external:
        class: 'link-external'
        type: 'url'
    mail:
        class: 'link-mail'
        type: 'mail'

buttons:
    link:
        properties:
            class:
                allowedClasses: 'link-arrow, link-page, link-folder, link-file, link-external, link-mail'

Here some screenshot for TsConfig code included:



We answered in slack; please do not crosspost. @mmasmoudi check https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/main/en-us/Configuration/Reference.html#allowedtypes - you seem to have that set somewhere in your config and probably omitted type "file"

@GarvinHicking: you should make an answer here, so anyone can find the 'solution' easier than in slack, which is not indexed in public. (and Mohamed-Masmoudi should accept the answer)

Last time I was slapped for providing an answer that was more a "look at X" so now I'm afraid of doing anything else than commenting

I don't have any code omitting the default file link handler, but thanks anyway.

Please check the Page TsConfig module and add the output to your Question:

The file tab must be removed somewhere. Either the TsConfig that removes the file tab is listed there or the preset, that is loaded.
EDIT 1:
If you have installed the EXT:lowlevel, then you can go to the "configuration" module:

There you can see, where the Presets are located:

In my answer to the following question, you can see, how to set your own custom preset:
TYPO3 RTE - allowedClasses is TSconfig have no effect
EDIT 2:
You could try to override the bootstrap theme. Add following to your EXT:your_sitepackage/ext_localconf.php:
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['bootstrap'] = 'EXT:your_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';

And then add the EXT:your_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml file:
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml" }

allowedTypes: 'page,url,file,folder,email,telephone'

If the file tab is not loaded then, somehow your bodytext RTE uses an other preset or there must be some TsConfig disabling the tab.

Thanks a lot Mogens, yes i have this same preset = bootstrap in my TsConfig, but i can't find it, do you have an idea where it could be from ?

Updated my answer.

Thanks i have also updated my question with more tries.

Updated my answer. If that doesn't work. Please show some screenshots of your RTE configuration. Especially the Page TsConfig.

I have tried to override like you mentioned above but still didn't work, i have updated my answer and attached the tsconfig code.

Sorry. Run out of ideas. Somewhere in your code there must be anything removing the file tab. So you should go through your sitepackage and deactivate stuff. Best way: Divide and conquer.
